Why do we use Z-gates in the following figure?



This is a picture of a 'T-gate gadget' and a proof for a circuit from “Quantum homomorphic encryption for circuits with low T-gate complexity” by Broadbent, Jeffrey (2015) (arXiv). My question is why the Z-gate is used in the second qubit circuit, even though it is possible to move the T-gate backwards without the $Z^k$ gate.

I haven't read the paper so I'm not entirely aware of the context and end goals of these circuits. However, I can point out when we might need to have $Z^k$.
It is best to first study the circuit in Figure 23.

Say we want to apply an $X$ gate to get $X|\psi\rangle$. To this end, we must post-select based on the measurement outcome $c$. If the measurement outcome is $c=1$, then we know that we have the desired state. If $c=0$, we must run the circuit again until we get $c=1$.
Now, regarding your question. Here, we have the same situation. Suppose we have a state $XZ|\psi\rangle$, and we want to apply the gate $T$. This means we want the state $XZT|\psi\rangle$ and not $XT|\psi\rangle$ or $ZT|\psi\rangle$.
If our input state is $XZ|\psi\rangle$, then $a = b = 1$. What happens when the outcome is $c=0$? In this case, we get
$$X^{a \oplus c} Z^{a \oplus b \oplus k \oplus a \cdot c}T|\psi\rangle = X Z^{k}T|\psi\rangle.$$
This is because $a \oplus b = 0$ and $a \cdot c = 0$ for $a,b=1$ and $c=0$. Therefore, to get the desired state $XZT|\psi\rangle$, we want to fix $k=1$. If we throw away $Z^k$, we'll get a different state $XT|\psi\rangle$.
If you only care about the gate $T$ being next to $|\psi\rangle$ and don't care whether $X$ or $Z$ are applied to $T|\psi\rangle$, then you may not need $Z^k$ gate.

I really appreciate your response.
It has really inspired me to understand this paper.
I have an additional question, although it is not directly related to my question.
The properties of some circuits, such as the X-Teloportation circuit, seem magical to me.
I don't understand it intuitively and I'm always doing computations to figure out if the circuit is true.
Is it necessary to have an intuitive understanding?

@yuria20, I guess it depends on an individual and experience in dealing with circuits. To me, it is also magical and  not very intuitive. However, to answer your original question I didn't do any computations. Instead I looked at output and inputs of circuits to quickly get a rough idea of what' was going on.
